Calculate node value based on its surrounding cells
I have a 2D float array of width * height elements and I want to generate a mesh using it as a heightmap. The texture I've generated from the array was also width * height, so the mesh should have (width+1) * (height+1) vertices in order to display the texture correctly.

So I sampled the 4 surrounding pixels for each vertex using a for loop, average them to get the height for that vertex.
This however was kind of inefficient (probably a good chunk of time spent on detecting edges and corners), and if I were to ignore having to make the mesh have (width+1) * (height+1) vertices, and leaving out a small part of the texture, the time it takes to generate the mesh gets cut in half.
Is there any algorithm to calculate the vertices height based on that float array that is quicker?

If you have a problem with your implementation, then provide that code, making sure it can be run out of the box and reproduces the issue you want to address. In case of timing issues, make sure it reproduces that issue (like it takes 2 minutes to run, but it has to finish in 1 minute).
